# Clash of the rewrites

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I have a category called 'neighborhoods'. I also have child categories within 'neighborhoods' E.G. Lakewood, Highland Park...

When I click 'highland park' the url is /pages/category/neighborhoods/highland-park

How can I change the htacces rules so that when viewing highland park the url would be neighborhoods/highland park/

I also have a post titled 'highland park' in order to have the neighborhoods page generate the 'highland park' category.  But when you click it takes you to the single post page.

I have a rewrite rule that works when you go to /neighborhoods/ it rewrites pages/category/neighbhorhoods/

but going to the child category brings you the post.

**EDIT:** here is the contents of the .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^sellers/? pages/sellers/
RewriteRule ^buyers/? pages/buyers/
RewriteRule ^neighborhoods/? pages/category/neighborhoods/
```

Comment: You need to check your permalink structure

Comment: My permalink structure is as is '/%category%/%postname%/'

Comment: can you post the contents of your .htaccess

Comment: RewriteRule ^sellers/?  pages/sellers/

RewriteRule ^buyers/?  pages/buyers/

RewriteRule ^neighborhoods/? pages/category/neighborhoods/

Comment: Have you added the RewriteEngine on to your .htacces or did you add the rewrite rules that apache gave you? Can you post a link to your site if wanted to see if it affects everyone? I also updated your question just waiting for approval

Comment: Yes I added the RewriteEngine on.  I cannot put a link because its hosted on our internal server.

It works when I go to /neighborhoods/ but when I go to the neighborhoods/highland-park/ it doesn't.

Comment: Here is how I am trying to work it on the .htaccess
     
`RewriteRule ^neighborhoods/(.*)/?  pages/category/neighborhoods/$1/
     RewriteRule ^neighborhoods/(.*)/? pages/index.php?category_name=$1[NC,QSA]`

Comment: ok so i just read my last reply and i ment did you add the rewrite rules that wordpress gave you. Other then that i dont know what is causing it. It could be a conflict with wordpress's structure. Normally you just add the rewrite rules wordpress gives you and thats it. Everything else is handled through wordpress's permalinks and database

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to register neighborhoods as a custom taxonomy and use that instead of categories. In your theme's functions.php file, you just need to add:

```
function neighborhoods_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'neighborhoods',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Neighborhoods' ),
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'neighborhoods_init' );
```

Next, go into your permalinks settings page and click save to be sure they get refreshed. Now when you edit posts, you'll have a new box in the sidebar for Neighborhoods. Your neighborhoods will now have links starting with /neighborhoods/! Of course, you'll have to port over your categories (and you'll probably want to remove the old categories to avoid confusion).

You have other options too when registering the taxonomy; see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy for all the details. For instance, you might consider adding `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'neighborhood' )` to the array since each neighborhood will be singular, not plural, making the URLs e.g. /neighborhood/highland-park/ (hey, I'm nit-picky).

Note: be sure to remove `RewriteRule ^neighborhoods/? pages/category/neighborhoods/` from your htaccess file, too.